# Login screen stuck in a loop

Tags: pi-3, login

I have tried several ideas such as:

chown pi:pi .Xauthority
choxn -R pi /home/pi

and I have deleted .Xauthority

But my pi keeps returning to the Shut-Down / Log-In screen no matter what I do.

I can get to terminal (ctrl-alt-F1) and do what ever I want, but the desktop won't finish loading.

Password is correct and working, just returns to the same screen.

Comment: Check free disk space and check the X log files

Comment: What kind of Pi are you running and what operating system?

Comment: What have you done that this happen?

Comment: Rc.local - tried to add a link to a python program, using graphics gui, to run on boot. Problem started after I removed the link. PI 3b Raspbian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar problem about 10 days ago.
And I had to reinstall the OS. Anything you change or delete related with boot can affect the OS badly. 
My suggestion is you should re install the OS

Comment: Rc.local - tried to add a link to a python program, using graphics gui, to run on boot.  Problem started after I removed the link.  PI 3b Raspbian

Comment: disk 16 gb about half full

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to solve this. Noted that you tried to *chown .Xauthority* with the -R switch and probably you tried it with a sudo, but again - try this version;

```
$ sudo chown pi:pi .Xauthority
$ sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo reboot
```

In case that doesn't work, since you have access to the CLI space at *[ALT]+[F1]*, you can always as a resort try to save necessary files by starting desktop with superuser with

```
$ sudo startx
```

Also have a look at for any quirkiness

```
$ sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

at the bottom just above "exit 0" and have a consideration with commenting out a potential line familiar from a recent install with a #

Reinstalling the OS as a solution is seldom necessary, anything can be fixed but in case there isn't any crucial work lost in the process it can be a good time saving option on some occasions.

Answer (score 0):

What the OP describes here is an `X11 Session Error`.
A more complete description comes from https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1219348&sid=a8a57224a0ccc492e7882ba151d5e4b9#p1219348

> This is the second time I've had this problem. Last time I gave up and rebuilt from a new download of Raspbian.
>
> *Expected functionality:* Pi3 (Raspbian, Stretch, up to date) is set to "Boot to desktop". When I turn on I get to the desktop and can do stuff. No password required. I have been using the pi this way since 23rd August with no problems whatsoever.
>
> *Symptoms after a reboot today - different to every other reboot I've done:*
>
> 1. Through SSH I can log in using default word "raspberry".
> 2. When connected to HDMI/keyboard/mouse instead getting to the desktop I get to a login prompt for pi on desktop screen3)
> 3. If I enter the correct password "raspberry" I get a black screen and then the login prompt comes back
> 4. If I enter an incorrect password deliberately it tells me, correctly, that I got it wrong.
> 5. Over SSH I added a new user with `useradd`, and using that user I can login successfully to the desktop at the login prompt .
> 6. Over SSH I changed the password for user pi, however when I try to use that to get to the desktop I get the symptoms in 3 above.

To summarize a few great answers including https://askubuntu.com/a/246858/146273 and https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/146273 ...

1. Check for `.xsession-errors.old` and/or `.xsession-errors.old` in your `$HOME` folder.
2. Read them and see if they tell you why your Display Manager has failed to hand off control to an X11 Session.
3. Be aware that because `/etc/X11/Xsession` is a shell script that sources many other shell scripts, the error message might not tell you the *true* file/location of the error, but it will help you discern the true *nature* of it.

Happy hunting. May the odds be ever in your favor.